# Why is unused value produced by catamorphism evaluated?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, recursion-schemes

I expected that the following code would run and exit immediately because `p` is never actually used, but instead, it runs for over 7 minutes and then is seemingly killed by the os.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad (liftM2)

main = print $ ((product' 1 >>= \p -> Nothing) :: Maybe Integer)

data Term f = In { out :: f (Term f) }

type Algebra f a = (f a -> a)

cata :: (Functor f) => Algebra f a -> Term f -> a
cata g t = g $ fmap (cata g) $ out t

type CoAlgebra f a = (a -> f a)

ana :: (Functor f) => CoAlgebra f a -> a -> Term f
ana g a = In $ fmap (ana g) $ g a

data A a = A (Maybe Integer) [a] | B deriving (Functor)

product' :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
product' i = cata h $ ana g $ fmap Just [i..1000]
  where g (x:xs) = A x $ replicate 10 xs
        g [] = B
        h (A k l) = foldr (liftM2 (*)) k l
        h B = Just 1
```

I thought this had to do with the bind operator, but the following code takes 9 seconds to run:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import Data.Foldable (foldr1)

main = print $ ((p >>= \p' -> Just p') :: Maybe Integer)

p :: Maybe Integer
p = foldr1 (liftM2 (*)) $ fmap Just [1..100000]
```

And this code exits immediately:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import Data.Foldable (foldr1)

main = print $ ((p >>= \p' -> Nothing) :: Maybe Integer)

p :: Maybe Integer
p = foldr1 (liftM2 (*)) $ fmap Just [1..100000]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `>>=` is strict in the first argument for `Maybe`, so even if `k >>= \x -> Nothing` is always going to be `Nothing`, `k` still gets evaluated to weak head normal form (which means in this case it has the form `Just _` or `Nothing`, where `_` can be an unevaluated thunk).

In your case, `k` is `product' 1`. You'll notice that just trying to evaluate that to weak normal head form hangs. In fact, you can see that `product' x` will probably take a really long time since it gets slower and slower as you have `1000 - x` larger and larger. On my laptop even `product' 995` takes a really long time (and that is with `-O2`).

---

Your benchmarks are not actually showing what you think they are. `>>=` really is strict in the first argument, but only to WNHF (not all the way down). To make a case to prove my point, notice that the following exits immediately.

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import Data.Foldable (foldr1)

main = print $ ((p >>= \_ -> Just 1) :: Maybe Integer)

p :: Maybe Integer
p = foldr1 (liftM2 (*)) $ fmap Just [1..100000]
```

The reason your second code snippet hangs is that it gets stuck trying to do the multiplication (which is pretty big) in order to print the result. If you ignore the result (as I do above), that doesn't happen - the result stays unevaluated. Another clue: your second code snippet hangs *after* having begun printing `Just`.

Comment: If `>>=` is strict in the first argument for Maybe, shouldn't the third code block in my question run as slowly as the second?

Comment: @bwroga Let me know if my edit answers your questions.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the difference between snippet 1 and 3. Are they both being evaluated to WNHF, but it's way more expensive in snippet 1?

Comment: Yeah, all snippets are going to WNHF. The hanging you get on your first snippet is due to the fact that `product'` is taking forever just get to WNHF. The hanging on your second snippet is due to the fact the multiplication that happens afterwards to display the number takes forever. My example shows you that the reason your snippets are different is _not_ the `Nothing` or `Just on the RHS of the `>>=`.